# Do I get XP in Apex Legends if I disconnect right after winning?

Tags: apex-legends

Today I was playing Apex Legends on my switch, and I actually won the match. However my switch was very low on charge so I had charge it. Due to the charger being a bit far away, I lost connection when I plugged it in. However, my screen showed the 'You are the Champion!' screen right before it disconnected. Do I still get the XP from the win?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

every match is normally saved in realtime, so you can leave the match at anytime to "cash in" the exp earned up until that moment, including your victory.

One way you can check this is at the main lobby there is a button to bring up the past match history, I don't know what the input is for switch, on the bottom right there is a list of icons, click the charts
[image]

This brings up past match results/exp breakdown.

Comment: Thank you! I checked the charts and my win was logged.